# AWS SDK JAVA S3 getting software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk-2.x

i am using AWS SDK Java s3 v2.17.255, Java 8 and facing below error. This error occur after application run for around 15-20 minutes and sometimes even after 30 minutes.

One observation is that this error is observed for **Cross Account bucket** access only. I have enabled cross account bucket access already.

I am closing **getObject()** request and if i don't do that i can see. "Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool" but error i am getting is as below.

```
 "software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:102)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:204)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:83)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:167)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$0(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:68)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:175)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:62)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:52)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:63)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.getObject(DefaultS3Client.java:4483)\
\   at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client.getObject(S3Client.java:7889)\
```

code looks like

```
public class ABC  {
    public ABC(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String bucketPath) {
        this.s3 = s3;
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
        this.bucketPath = bucketPath;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return s3GetObjectResponse();
    }

    public long getLastModified() {
        return s3GetObjectResponse().response().lastModified().getEpochSecond();
    }


    protected void finalize() {
        if(getObjectResponse != null) {
            try {
                getObjectResponse.close();
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                sLogger.warn("Unable to close GetObjectResponse", ioe);
            }
        }
    }

    private String bucketName;
    private String bucketPath;
    private S3Client s3;
    private GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest;

    private ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> getObjectResponse;
    private static Logger sLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ABC.class.getName());

    private ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> s3GetObjectResponse() {
        if(getObjectResponse == null) {
            getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(bucketPath)
                    .build();
            getObjectResponse = s3.getObject(getObjectRequest);
        }
        return getObjectResponse;
    }
}
```

Please suggest what wrong i am doing. ABC objects are created almost 60-100 per minute with a single S3Client.

Comment: Posted same in AWS SDK JAVA V2 github discussion https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/discussions/3397